# JavaApplet with Socket Server, refresh page does't close the Port

Tags: java, applet, serversocket

I have a JavaApplet running in Firefox, when I refresh the page, the JavaApplet reloads, but I am getting the following error:

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

I have ServerSocket.close(); in finally like everywhere. Not sure what I am missing, please help.

Comment: Where are you seeing the exception, server or client?  From the stack trace I would guess on the server, in which case the problem is in server code not the applet.

Answer (score 1):

The PlugIn doesn't immediately stop threads, and even when it does it's problematic how to do that. You should override an `Applet` lifecycle method. I think that's the `stop` method. Probably start again in `start`, but I forget browsers peculiarities (should be quite uniform since Java Activator). Of course, binding to a server socket on a specific address isn't very applet friendly.